# Disable button on if...else

Tags: jquery

I have some JQuery which I would like to use to disable a button on a php page should a particular result come back.

**JQuery**

```
...
success:function(data){
            $("#value10").html(data.price);
            $("#total").html(data.newtotal);
            $("#toohigh").html(data.toohigh);
            if(data.toohigh === 1) {
                $("#subbut").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            } else if(data.toohigh === 0){
                $("#subbut").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
```

**php**

```
<button type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary align-content-center" id="subbut">
```

I've tried all sorts of different possible solutions none of which disable the button when `data.toohigh` equals 1

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by your variable `data.toohigh` is not matched with your condition `1` or `0` or problem with datatype

**Try this code**

```
...
success:function(data){
            $("#value10").html(data.price);
            $("#total").html(data.newtotal);
            $("#toohigh").html(data.toohigh);
            if(data.toohigh == '1') {
                $("#subbut").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            } else if(data.toohigh == '0'){
                $("#subbut").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
```

Comment: `$("#toohigh").html(data.toohigh);` only returns a `0` or `1` anyway I can force the match?

Comment: put `==` instead of `===` and check the type of your varible like `typeof(data.toohigh)`

Comment: I still get the correct `0` or `1` return but the button doesn't change state

Comment: please see my editable code above if it's work

Comment: Works with one small change `if(data.toohigh == '0'){
                $("#subbut").attr('disabled', false);
            }`

Answer (score 0):

you can try using prop like below:

```
   if(data.toohigh === 1) {
        $("#subbut").prop('disabled', true);
    } else if(data.toohigh === 0){
        $("#subbut").prop('disabled', false);
    }
```